# When does this image of Shinji Ikari sitting in a folding chair appear?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion

I'm referring to this image:

[image: Shinji in a chair, facing right]

At the very beginning of episode 25 a very similar image occurs:

[image: Shinji in a chair, facing left]

However, even after re-watching the final two episodes a few times, I can't find the image.

Is there some specific release of the episodes that the first image occurs in, or does it even not occur in the series at all?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I remember seeing it in the series when he's talking to Ritsuko, but I can't recall the episode. Around 14-17, I think, but I'll have to check later (if no one else answers before then).

Comment: Pretty sure that image never appears in the original TV series or movies. I *think* it's from either promotional/artbooks or from one of the games. Don't know offhand

Answer (score 1):

Using WAIT to identify the screen gives us EP#25, 02:31

Preview of the scene can be seen here:
https://whatanime.ga/?url=https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScRR6.jpg

Edit: 
Never mind, you meant the first one.
This doesn't seem to appear.